# Submit button, next step

Tags: php, jquery, html, database

I am done with the search page where the user enters the information and select from the drop-list. I've also added the button AddList where you can have more than one search form with tag names changed. All of the searches will eventually be executed in one Submit button and each search will go in one single query. My table caries all the information and tuples contain only numbers.

**UPDATED:** I tried changing the input type of the input tags but the enable and disable functions can't seem to work on integers, only on text fields. How can I fix that?

My submission is tomorrow, and here is my search code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#exactButton').live('click', function(){
                $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().removeAttr('disabled');

                $(this).prev().prev().prev().attr('disabled',true);
                $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().attr('disabled',true); 
            });

            $('#rangeButton').live('click',function(){
                $(this).prev().prev().removeAttr('disabled');
                $(this).prev().prev().prev().removeAttr('disabled');

                $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().attr('disabled',true);
            });

        })
    </script>
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
 <button id="button">Add List</button><br><br>
        <form id ="form" name="search" method="get" action="test.php">
            <div id="div">
                <select name ="select" >
                    ...options...
                </select>

                Value:<input type="text" name="exact" id="exactField" />

                From: <input type="text" name="from" id="fromField" />
                To: <input type="text" name="to" id="toField" />

                <br>
                <input type="button" name="answer" value="Range" id="rangeButton" />
                <input type="button" name="answer" value="Exact" id="exactButton" />

            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit"name="search" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: they will all be in the $_GET global array, once submitted

Comment: prev().prev().prev().prev().prev() ? debugging will be frustrating, you may want an easier access to those elements

Comment: @Frederik I don't care for debugging, my concern is how to get all different submissions, if any, that was chosen by the user..including the cloned ones.

Answer (score 0):

as Dagon said, you will see all submitted parameters in the URL since you are submitting the form with method `GET`. here is very good explanation for this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Comment: I actually have this method written in the test.php. However, I need a way that acknowledges all submitted parameters in order to add them in a query statement. And I have no idea to implement a _GET array. Does it need a loop to do so? I am saying that based on my java experience. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One idea: 
add some custom attributtes to the elements (to the clones too).

```
this.attr("mycustomattribute","somevalue");
```

after this, you can get all elements on the page with your custom attribute and your value.

```
divs = $('div[mycustomattribute="somevalue"]'); //should give all div container with attribute "mycustomattribute" with value "somevalue" 
divs.each(function(){ 
   console.log(this,$(this).attr('name'));//show expression (for debug)
});
```

then you can collect this elements, serialize it and add it to your post   Not tested, but an idea.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, it's already there.

`print_r($_GET);` will list all parameters sent by GET method

`print_r($_POST);` will list all parameters send by POST method.

Then, of course, you will need to iterate in the array to include each values in your query statement.

Comment: thank you so much! works perfectly and yes I will work on the array iteration. Another question, if I add a AND/OR drop List, is there a way I can include it in my query?

Comment: Assuming that there is a AND/OR drop list for each values which also send a GET parameter, you may proceed with : first value is the operator (AND/OR), the second one is the value, so each odd numbers are operators and the others are values.

Comment: Otherwise, you may dynamically add a symbol at the beginning of the value just before it is sent. For example AND:+ OR:* so instead of having an extra parameter for each values you will have values like "+someValue" and "*someOtherValue" which you can deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can naming input with prefix or suffix correspond to sequence that user click to add list and add those set of inputs to only form.

```
<form id ="form" name="search" method="get" action="test.php">
    <div>
            <select name ="select[1]" >
                ...options...
            </select>

            Value:<input type="text" name="exact[1]" class="exactField" />

            From: <input type="text" name="from[1]" class="fromField" />
            To: <input type="text" name="to[1]" class="toField" />

            <br>
            <input type="button" name="answer[1]" value="Range" class="rangeButton" />
            <input type="button" name="answer[1]" value="Exact" class="exactButton" />

        </div>
    <div>
            <select name ="select[2]" >
                ...options...
            </select>

            Value:<input type="text" name="exact[2]" class="exactField" />

            From: <input type="text" name="from[2]" class="fromField" />
            To: <input type="text" name="to[2]" class="toField" />

            <br>
            <input type="button" name="answer[2]" value="Range" class="rangeButton" />
            <input type="button" name="answer[2]" value="Exact" class="exactButton" />

        </div>
.
.
.
        <br>
        <input type="submit"name="search" value="Submit">
</form>
```